# Parcel throws error when I want to include google app script variable

Tags: google-apps-script, parceljs

I'm trying to pass a variable to html template in app sheet.

I'm trying to use parcel to compile all the code in one html file since app script works like that.

To receive variable in html I would need to use something like this:

```
<script>
 var doc_id = <?!= doc_id ?>;
</script>
```

However when I try to compile that I get an error

Build failed.

@parcel/transformer-js: Expression expected

```
    16 |     <script>
  > 17 |       var doc_id = <?!= doc_id ?>;
  >    |                              ^
    18 |     </script>
```

Is there a way to make parcel ignore error on some line of code or to fix this in some other way?

Comment: Try attaching it to the template as show here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#pushing_variables_to_templates.  All you need is a printing scriplet

Comment: I don't see how this addresses my question in any way. I know how to pass a variable, problem is that it can't be compiled by parcel because that's invalid js.

Comment: Yes using a template requires an evaulate method prior to rendering

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-template

Comment: @Cooper Parcel is a local development tool like clasp https://parceljs.org/

Comment: Related: https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/544 You may want to create a new issue or comment in #544